# Vaadin TreeTable Filtering

Tags: tree, vaadin

I use TreeTable with custom datasource. I want to filter it and expand items that match particular conditions. But the only method, that I found, is `setCollapsed(itemId, collapsed)` 
But using this method for great amount of items will break the performance. Any suggestions how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an SimpleStringFilter (or your own implementation of Filter) to the container of the treeTable ([Vaadin API](https://vaadin.com/api/) for more info).

Adding an filter to a container will retains only the matching item in the container data source (the `Container.getItemsIds().size()` will return the exact number of matching items).

After that you can use the `setCollapsed()` method with fewer items.

Regards.